# Energy flows in the core also responsible for another of the planet’s unique

Tags: electromagnetism, earth, geophysics

Energy flows in the core also responsible for
another of the planet’s unique features: a
strong magnetic field. Scientists believe that
the earth has had a magnetic field for at
least 3.5 billion years. The basic mechanism
of magnetic field generation is a dynamo
process, in which the kinetic energy of
convective motion in the Earth’s liquid core
is converted into magnetic energy. The
velocity of this fluid movement is on the
order of 10 kilometers per year. The rotation
of the earth couples this motion into a
circulation that generates electric currents,
and the electric currents in turn generate a
magnetic field according to classical
electromagnetic theory.
Since this process operates without an
external energy source, the geodynamo is
said to be self-sustaining. Without that
regenerative process the electric currents
and the associated magnetic field would
dissipate in about 15,000 years.
Sources
Department of Geological Sciences, San
Diego State University, The earth's internal
energy and internal structure, Accessed 27
June 2007.
Lawrence Berkeley National Laboratory,
The truth about Earth's core?, Accessed 27
June 2007.
Pennsylvania State University, Probing
Question: What heats the earth's core?,
Accessed 27 June 2007.
ScienceDaily, Discovery Of Earth's Inner,
Innermost Core Confirmed, Accessed 21
August 2008.

My question is that the earths magnetic field is caused due to its mass or its core

Comment: Hi Hash. Your question is OK. But the way you're asking each time and the way you've formatted your post may sometimes send users to boredom. If you copy something from somewhere, please use the hyperlinks for inserting the reference. And this applies to both Q & As. In case of questions, the users can look at the links if they don't understand the question deeply. For answers, it's called *plagiarizing* if you don't use the links and we find them..! Anyways, please try to format your post ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In fact, everything till now about the magnetic field (*of earth*) are just proposed theories. And, the [dynamo process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_magnetic_field#Physical_origin) is the currently accepted one. The outer core is made of some kind of iron at its liquid state and it's conductive. Since magnetic fields are caused by electric currents ($\text M$ around $\text E$), we've assumed that somehow a current loop is produced at the iron layers (motion due to convection) and is sustained by the rotation of Earth (Coriolis effect). Still, there are a large number of models trying to predict the real event.

> My question is that the earth's magnetic field is caused due to its mass or its core?

If this is your question, then you can do a googling. Every single search query results that the magnetic field is due to its **core**. By mass, if you're thinking about GR - [Gravitomagnetism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitomagnetism) is a nice article...